# Why is the variation of powers of reduced density matrices of an interval given by integrals of the Stress tensor around that interval

Tags: entropy, conformal-field-theory, path-integral

I have a questions which seems trivial but I don't know how to handle it properly..
In Cardy and Calabreses derivation of the entanglement entropy of a line (https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0405152) in CFT's they consider a manifold which is equal to n copies of the complex plane, where the i'th copy is glued to the i+1'st copy along a interval between two points, say $[u,w]$. 
They describe that performing a path integral over this n-sheeted surface is equal to computing the trace of the n'th power of the reduced density matrix for the interval $[u,w]$. 
So essentially one looks at objects of the form $\int D\phi \exp(-S[\mathcal{R}_n]])$ where $\mathcal{R}_n$ is this n-sheeted riemann surface one obtains from gluing the copies of the complex plane together.
Then they say that if one performs a conformal transformation of all the sheets, $z \rightarrow z+ \epsilon(z),\bar{z} \rightarrow \bar{z} + \bar{\epsilon}(\bar{z})$ the effect in the path integrals is the insertion of
$ \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_C T(z)\epsilon(z) dz- c.c$ into the path integral where $C$ is a contour surrounding the interval $[u,w]$. I see that the variation of this path integral gives me something like
$\int D\phi \sum_n \int d^2 x \partial_{\mu} \epsilon j^{\mu}\exp(-S[\mathcal{R}_n])$ If $\epsilon$ would be supported only on a compact neighbourshood of the interval, then I would see that stokes theorem gives the integral $ \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_C T(z)\epsilon(z) dz- c.c$. However if $\epsilon$ is defined on the whole of the complex plane, I have no more or less rigorous argument why only the contour integral survives.

I see that the expectation value of the stress tensor needs to have a branch cut along the interval so I thought that maybe something similar to the residue theorem holds and one can argue that this contour integral is the only nonvanishing contribution, however all my search ended fruitless.

Thanks and have a nice day